# For $a \in M$, a metric space, prove $A = \{x \in M: 1 \leq d(x, a) \leq 5\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

For $a \in M$, a metric space, prove $A = \{x \in M: 1 \leq d(x, a) \leq 5\}$ is closed.

The below uses that the complement $M\setminus A$ is open. I just want to check if my process if correct.

$M\setminus A = \{x \in M: d(x, a) < 1 \,or\, d(x, a) > 5\}$

The open ball around $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ is given as:

$B_\epsilon(x) = \{y \in M: d(x, y) < \epsilon\}$

**Case 1**

Let $\epsilon = 1 - d(x, a) > 0$

$\therefore d(x,y) < 1 - d(x,a)$

$\implies d(x,y) + d(x,a)< 1$

So by the Triangle Inequality:

$d(y, a) \leq d(x,y) + d(x,a)< 1$

$\therefore y \in M\setminus A$

**Case 2**

Let $\epsilon = d(x, a) - 5 > 0$

$\therefore d(x,y) < d(x, a) - 5$

$\implies d(x,y) - d(x,a) < -5$

$\implies d(x,a) - d(x,y) > 5$

So by the reverse of the Triangle Inequality:

$d(y, a) \geq d(x,a) - d(x,y) > 5$

$\therefore y \in M\setminus A$

$\therefore M\setminus A$ open

$\therefore A$ closed

Is this correct?

Comment: Just prove that distances $d(a, -): M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and avoid all this, much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It am posting it as an answer because i can not comment. Your proof essentially fine. But there are other easer ways to do it. You can write $M\setminus A$ as a union of two sets. Or you can implement the concept of closure of $A$, namely, $A$ is closed iff $A=\overline{A}$. To do so, take a sequence ${x_n}$ in $A$ which converges to a limit $x \in M$ and prove that $x \in A$.

Let $x_n$ be sequence in $A$ such that  $d(x_n, x)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. We want to show that $x \in A$, namely, we want to show each limit point is in $A$, (A' \subset A).

Since $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Fix $\epsilon >0$, there is $N>0$ such that $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$ for all $n >N$.

For the sake of contradiction, assume $d(x,a) >5$, then from the triangle inequality we have

$$5 < d(x,a) \leq d(x,x_n) + d(x_n,a) < \epsilon + d(x_n,a) \Rightarrow 5 < d(x_n,a),$$

which contradicts the assumption that $x_n$ is in $A$. Then we have $d(x,a) \leq 5$.

Similarly, assume $d(x,a) <1$, and obtain a contradiction. Then we have $1\leq d(x,a)\leq 5$ which implies $x \in A$.

Comment: Thanks Ali. It struck me to split M\A into a union of two open sets after after I posted this. The latter method you mention, I am aware this can be used but not sure how to show it. Thanks

Comment: @number8 I added some explanation that might help.